# 'Module build failed: Error: Couldn't find preset "es2015" relative to directory' from newly created gatsby project

Tags: npm, nvm, gatsby

I have created a project following these steps:

```
npm install -g gatsby
gatsby new dev-blog
cd dev-blog
npm install
```

Then I try to start by project by

```
gatsby develop --host localhost --port 9000
```

At this point it throws an exception:

```
Failed to require /Users/antkong/wd/blogs/gatsby/dev-blog/html.js
./html.js
Module build failed: Error: Couldn't find preset "es2015" relative to directory "/Users/antkong/wd"
```

How can I fix this problem?

**Edit**

OS: `OSX 10.12.4`

```
Darwin mymac.local 16.5.0 Darwin Kernel Version 16.5.0: Fri Mar  3 16:52:33 PST 2017; root:xnu-3789.51.2~3/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

npm: `3.10.10`

node: `6.10.2`

Full stacktrace:

```
❯❯ npm run develop   
> gatsby-starter-default@1.0.0 develop /Users/antkong/wd/blogs/gatsby/dev-blog
> gatsby develop

Failed to require /Users/antkong/wd/blogs/gatsby/dev-blog/html.js
./html.js
Module build failed: Error: Couldn't find preset "es2015" relative to directory "/Users/antkong/wd"
    at /Users/antkong/wd/blogs/gatsby/dev-blog/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:293:19
    at Array.map (native)
    at OptionManager.resolvePresets (/Users/antkong/wd/blogs/gatsby/dev-blog/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:275:20)
    at OptionManager.mergePresets (/Users/antkong/wd/blogs/gatsby/dev-blog/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:264:10)
    at OptionManager.mergeOptions (/Users/antkong/wd/blogs/gatsby/dev-blog/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:249:14)
    at OptionManager.init (/Users/antkong/wd/blogs/gatsby/dev-blog/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:368:12)
    at File.initOptions (/Users/antkong/wd/blogs/gatsby/dev-blog/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:212:65)
    at new File (/Users/antkong/wd/blogs/gatsby/dev-blog/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:135:24)
    at Pipeline.transform (/Users/antkong/wd/blogs/gatsby/dev-blog/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/pipeline.js:46:16)
    at transpile (/Users/antkong/wd/blogs/gatsby/dev-blog/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js:46:20)
    at /Users/antkong/wd/blogs/gatsby/dev-blog/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/fs-cache.js:79:18
    at ReadFileContext.callback (/Users/antkong/wd/blogs/gatsby/dev-blog/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/fs-cache.js:15:14)
    at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterOpen [as oncomplete] (fs.js:366:13)

 @ (webpack)-require/lib/webpackRequireEntrypoint.js 1:20-41
```

I am also using nvm

```
❯❯ nvm list                                                                      
->      v6.10.2
         system
default -> v6 (-> v6.10.2)
node -> stable (-> v6.10.2) (default)
stable -> 6.10 (-> v6.10.2) (default)
iojs -> N/A (default)
lts/* -> lts/boron (-> v6.10.2)
lts/argon -> v4.8.2 (-> N/A)
lts/boron -> v6.10.2
```

Comment: I ran these same steps (minus the last `npm install` as that's not necessary as `gatsby new` installs packages for you) and things just worked.

Comment: Perhaps add some info about your environment? Version of node, OS, etc.?

Comment: Gatsby has a default .babelrc which is why starters don't include their own.

Comment: I think you are right. If I repeat the above steps in a newly built ubuntu 17, the problem does not appear (Just to need to make sure `/usr/bin/node` exists). Not sure what happened to my local environment. Will update the question with more info.

Answer (score 0):

`gabsty new` does not create a `.babelrc` that is needed by `babel`. The error is caused by the missing `.babelrc`.

Here is the content of my `.babelrc`:

```
{
  "presets": ["react", "es2015", "stage-0"],
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "presets": ["react-hmre"]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Gatsby includes a default Babel configuration so sites don't need their own unless they need custom babel plugins to be added.